# On the cyclicity of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$, for $p$ a prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

Let $p$ be a prime. The group $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ acts regularly on the set of generators of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Therefore, for every $i,j=1,\dots,p-1$, there is one and only one $\sigma_{ij}\in S_{p-1}$ such that:
\begin{equation} \begin{cases} \sigma_{ij}(i)=j\space\space\text{ (by the regularity of the action)}\\ \sigma_{ij}(1)=ji^{-1}\space\space\text{ (by the linearity of }\sigma_{ij}) \\ \sigma_{ij}(k)\ne k,\text{ for every }k\space(i\ne j)\\ \Sigma=\{\sigma_{ij}, i,j =1,\dots,p-1\} \text{ is an abelian subgroup of order }p-1 \text{ of }S_{p-1}
\text{ (so there are repetitions)} \tag1 \end{cases} \end{equation}

For example, for $p=5$ the normal Klein four-subgroup $\Sigma=\{(),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}\le S_4$, with the identifications:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\sigma_{ii}=(),\text{ for }i=1,2,3,4 \\
&\sigma_{12}=\sigma_{21}=\sigma_{34}=\sigma_{43}=(12)(34) \\
&\sigma_{13}=\sigma_{31}=\sigma_{24}=\sigma_{42}=(13)(24) \\
&\sigma_{14}=\sigma_{41}=\sigma_{23}=\sigma_{32}=(14)(23) \\
\end{alignat}
fulfils the first and third equations in $(1)$, but not the second (for example, $\sigma_{34}(1)=2$, but $4.3^{-1}=4.3^3=4.27=108=3$).

Besides, some elements of the non-normal Klein four-subgroups of $S_4$ fail to move all the generators of $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, so they do not fulfil $(1)$ either.

On the other hand, $\Sigma=\langle(1243)\rangle=$ $\{(),(1243),(14)(23),(1342)\}$ with the identifications:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\sigma_{ii}=(),\text{ for }i=1,2,3,4 \\
&\sigma_{12}=\sigma_{24}=\sigma_{43}=\sigma_{31}=(1243) \\
&\sigma_{14}=\sigma_{41}=\sigma_{23}=\sigma_{32}=(14)(23) \\
&\sigma_{13}=\sigma_{34}=\sigma_{42}=\sigma_{21}=(1342) \\
\end{alignat}
fulfils $(1)$. In fact:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\sigma_{12}(1)=2\text{ and }2.1^{-1}=2.1=2 \\
&\sigma_{24}(1)=2\text{ and }4.2^{-1}=4.2^3=4.8=32=2 \\
&\sigma_{43}(1)=2\text{ and }3.4^{-1}=3.4=12=2 \\
&\sigma_{31}(1)=2\text{ and }1.3^{-1}=1.3^3=27=2 \\
& \\
&\sigma_{14}(1)=4\text{ and }4.1^{-1}=4.1=4 \\
&\sigma_{41}(1)=4\text{ and }1.4^{-1}=4 \\
&\sigma_{23}(1)=4\text{ and }3.2^{-1}=3.2^3=3.8=24=4 \\
&\sigma_{32}(1)=4\text{ and }2.3^{-1}=2.3^3=2.27=54=4 \\
& \\
&\sigma_{13}(1)=3\text{ and }3.1^{-1}=3 \\
&\sigma_{34}(1)=3\text{ and }4.3^{-1}=4.3^3=4.27=108=3 \\
&\sigma_{42}(1)=3\text{ and }2.4^{-1}=2.4=8=3 \\
&\sigma_{21}(1)=3\text{ and }1.2^{-1}=2^3=8=3 \\
\end{alignat}
Therefore, $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)=\{\psi_i,i=1,2,3,4\}$, where $\psi_i(0)=0$ and $\psi_i(j)=(1243)^i(j)$ for $j=1,2,3,4$, and hence $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.

My question: is $(1)$ constraining enough to force by itself $\Sigma$ to be cyclic (and hence $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$) for every $p$, like it does for $p=5$?

Comment: I think it just forces the automorphism group to be $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, since the second condition is just requiring linearity. So I don't think this really buys you anything.

Comment: @reuns, for $p=5$, the element $(12)(34)$ must be the repetitions $\sigma_{12}=$ $\sigma_{21}=$ $\sigma_{34}=$ $\sigma_{43}$ in the sought $\Sigma$, whose elements must fulfil $(1)$. But $\sigma_{34}(1)\ne 4.3^{-1}$. So it doesn't build up an automorphism of $Aut(\Bbb Z_p)$. I think.

Comment: It is not hard to show that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ (Here $m$ is not necessarily prime) is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Z}_m*$, the latter being $\{\ \bar{k}| \ \gcd(k,m)=1\}$ with the multiplication as the binary operation (i.e. $\bar{a}\bar{b}=\bar{ab}$). And $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ is cyclic iff $m$ has at least one primitive root. Elementary number theory says that every prime number has at least one primitive root.